# Parse value from http web response stream

Tags: c#, json, httpwebresponse

I have a httpwebresponse stream in this format as a string.

```
{"totalUsersCount":
[{"AccountStatus":1,"TotalUsers":53,"MemberUsers":33,"CrimsonUsers":20},
{"AccountStatus":2,"TotalUsers":7,"MemberUsers":7,"CrimsonUsers":0},
{"AccountStatus":3,"TotalUsers":44,"MemberUsers":37,"CrimsonUsers":7},
{"AccountStatus":6,"TotalUsers":28718,"MemberUsers":28718,"CrimsonUsers":0},
{"AccountStatus":5,"TotalUsers":3,"MemberUsers":3,"CrimsonUsers":0}]}
```

I would want to parse out the value of totalUsersCount alone so that I get the parsed out result in this format

```
[{"AccountStatus":1,"TotalUsers":53,"MemberUsers":33,"CrimsonUsers":20},
{"AccountStatus":2,"TotalUsers":7,"MemberUsers":7,"CrimsonUsers":0},
{"AccountStatus":3,"TotalUsers":44,"MemberUsers":37,"CrimsonUsers":7},       
{"AccountStatus":6,"TotalUsers":28718,"MemberUsers":28718,"CrimsonUsers":0},
{"AccountStatus":5,"TotalUsers":3,"MemberUsers":3,"CrimsonUsers":0}]
```

If the result is in json format we could easily parse it out. But this result is in string format. I tried to jsonize the string using Json.parse and then apply json parsing. But that didn't help. May be I didn't try it the right way. Could anyone help?

Comment: **How** didn't that help? What happened? What code did you write?

Comment: http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/Samples.htm#

Answer (score 2):

It is easy using [Json.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/). Just declare your concrete classes and then deserialize.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(yourJsonString);

foreach (var item in root.TotalUsersCount)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.AccountStatus);
}

var allusers = root.TotalUsersCount.Sum(u => u.TotalUsers);
```

---

```
public class TotalUsersCount
{
    public int AccountStatus { get; set; }
    public int TotalUsers { get; set; }
    public int MemberUsers { get; set; }
    public int CrimsonUsers { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<TotalUsersCount> TotalUsersCount { get; set; }
}
```

---

You can also use the built-in `System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer`

```
var root = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<RootObject>(yourJsonString);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use JSON.NET. Its better than any other library for Json.

If you've got a string, DeSerialize it like this

```
JsonObject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringToPass);
```

It would provide you with a JsonObject since you're working with JsonArrays, try this

```
JsonArray arr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(stringToPass); 
// should start with [
```

For more by developer, go here: http://james.newtonking.com/json